# ¿Cómo puedo separar una fila en múltiples columnas?

Tags: r, condiciones, bucles

El problema es el siguiente, tengo una fila de datos como podría ser:

```
datos <- rbind(NA, 3,8,2,NA,1,2,NA,3,8,9,8)
```

Y quiero transformar esa columna, en una **matriz que se inicie cada vez que aparezca un NA**. Algo como esto:

[image: matriz]

He intentado hacer un loop, con un if dentro que cada vez que aparezca un NA salte a empezar una nueva columna, pero no he conseguido nada. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Diego!, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas, saludos y suerte!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando simplemente la paquetería base de R, puedes hacer esto:

```
datos <- rbind(NA, 3,8,2,NA,1,2,NA,3,8,9,8)

l <- split(datos, cumsum(as.numeric(is.na(datos))))
sapply(l, "[", i = seq_len(max(sapply(l, length))))
```

Salida:

```
      1  2  3
[1,] NA NA NA
[2,]  3  1  3
[3,]  8  2  8
[4,]  2 NA  9
[5,] NA NA  8
```

Explicación:

- Con `cumsum(as.numeric(is.na(datos)))` generamos grupos a partir de la aparición de cada `NA`, algo así: `[1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3`
- Luego usando `split`, generamos una lista de listas con los elementos de cada grupo
- Por ultimo: `sapply(l, "[", i = seq_len(max(sapply(l, length))))`, transformamos la lista en una matriz rellenando las "celdas" faltantes con `NA's`.